# Tree creation using generics in c#

Tags: c#, generics, data-structures, generic-programming, huffman-code

I am new to c# i have just completed a `huffman tree` and now next step is to make it `generic` i mean this `symbol`should work for every `data type`. Since i am c# beginner i need some basic idea to do that.

My huffman tree consists of 3 classes. Class huffman, node and MyClass(which contains the main function) where `freq` is the number of times the `symbol` repeats they are structured as given below:

```
namespace final_version_Csharp
{
    public Class Huffman 
    {
        public classNode 
        {
            public Node next, left, right;
            public int symbol;
            public int freq;
        }
        public Node root;
    }
    public void huffman_node_processing() 
    {
        //done the addition of two minimum freq here
    }
    public void GenerateCode(Node parentNode, string code) 
    {
        //done the encoding work here
    }

    public class MyClass 
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args) 
          {
            Huffman ObjSym = new Huffman(args); //object creation by reading the data fron a file at   sole argument
            //All other methods are here
            ObjSym.huffman_node_processing(); //this for adding the two minimum nodes
            ObjSym.GenerateCode(ObjSym.root, ""); //this for encoding
           }
    }
}
```

Could some one please help me in making this "symbol" work for all data types like "short","long" etc.

Comment: When you say generic do you mean that one node could have an int symbol and one a string symbol within the same tree or do you want to be able to create a tree where symbol is always the same (for example string)

Comment: @BobVale actually i am reading a binary file in order to create freq of the symbols (which could be of the form 1110111..). The "symbol" must work for 1 byte or 2 byte etc. Have you understood now ?

Answer (score 2):

If I am understanding you correctly, you would basically do something like

```
namespace final_version_Csharp
{
    public Class Huffman<K> where K :  IComparable<K>
    {
        public classNode<K> 
        {
            public Node next, left, right;
            public K symbol;
            public int freq;
        }
        public Node root;
    }
...
    public class MyClass 
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args) 
          {
            Huffman ObjSym = new Huffman<int>(); 
            //All other methods are here
            ObjSym.huffman_node_processing(); //this for adding the two minimum nodes
            ObjSym.GenerateCode(ObjSym.root, ""); //this for encoding
           }
    }
}
```

Comment: Server, Thanks for the help but what if the freq is float ?

Comment: You have, say, 2.5 occurrences of a particular symbol?

Comment: @505 I couldn't understand why you have kept <int> in object creation  after "new Huffman" ."Huffman ObjSym = new Huffman<int>();" ?

Comment: That's what you would do if your symbols are actually ints. You can supply any type there as long as it implements IComparable.

Comment: You mean suppose if i read a binary file and then i read symbol which of "int" type after that i read it of "short" or "ulong type", so your  <int> will type caste it to "int type" ? Am i understanding correctly ? I wanted to make "symbol" for all "int", "short", "ulong" etc. Is your code doing the same?

Comment: So your input contains multiple types of data? Since you have to be able to compare them in order to find out which are duplicates I think you will need to settle on a datatype that can encompass them all.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/50058/discussion-between-user234839-and-500-internal-server-error)

Answer (score 1):

All you need to use here is an `interface`

```
public interface IMyType
{
    int Symbol { get; set; }
    int Freq { get; set; }
}
```

then just use this for all classes you want to be able to work with generically. So

```
public class ClassA : IMyType
{
    ...
    public int Symbol { get; set; }
    public int Freq { get; set; }
    ...
}

public class ClassB : IMyType
{
    ...
    public int Symbol { get; set; }
    public int Freq { get; set; }
    ...
}
```

Then you can use these object in methods like this

```
void SomeMethod(IMyType o)
{
    o.Symbol = 1;
    o.Freq = 2;
    ...
}

IMyType a = new ClassA();
IMyType b = new ClassB();
SomeMethod(a);
SomeMethod(b);
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for the help but i don't have to use Interface.

Comment: Then I am afraid I don't understand the question... Sorry.